# What are the differences between getRawSomething and getSomething methods on Archetypes contents (eg. ATNewsItem)?

Tags: plone, archetypes

What are the differences between `getRawSomething` and `getSomething` methods on Archetypes contents (eg. ATNewsItem)?

For exemple, what is the difference between `getRawImage` and `getImage`? Or `getRawRelatedItems` and `getRelatedItems`? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRaw*` gives you the direct, unprocessed raw data as stored on the object. The `get*` methods are allowed to transform that data in some way as needed.

For example, `TextField` fields will transform text to safe HTML when using `get`, but `getRaw()` gives you the untransformed data, be that markdown, restructuredtext or unprocessed HTML.

From the [developer documentation](http://developer.plone.org/content/archetypes/fields.html#raw-access):

> Archetypes has two kinds of access methods:
>
> - normal, `getSomething()`, which filters output;
> - raw, the so-called edit accessor, `getRawSomething()` which does not filter output.

When you want to edit the current contents of a field, use `getRaw*`, when rendering the contents, use `get*`.

Specifically, related items are stored in a reference field, where the `getRaw()` method returns object UIDs, the `get()` method returns objects, having first resolved the UIDs for you.

Image fields, like file fields, will wrap the data in the associated object type (`OFS.Image` for image fields) if not already that type when using `.get()` but return whatever the underlying storage has got for `.getRaw()`. Usually the object is already wrapped though.